# Adding custom options to all products of a certain type on save

Tags: magento-1, custom-options

I have created some custom product types that extend from simple products. These product types will all have the same custom options added, so I'd like to just set those options on the product when saved as well as removing any other options that might have been added accidentally.

In my product type model, I have added the following `save()` method:

```
//My_Module_Model_Product_Type_Customtype extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Type_Simple

public function save($product = null)
{
    $option = array(
        'title' => 'My Options',
        'type' => 'field',
        'is_require' => 0,
        'price' => 5,
        'price_type' => 'fixed',
        'sku' => 'mysku'
    );

    $product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
    $optionInstance = $product->getOptionInstance();
    $optionInstance->unsetOptions();
    $optionInstance->addOption($option);
    $product->setHasOptions(1);
    $optionInstance->setProduct($product);

    return $this;
}
```

When I load an existing product of my type that does not have custom options assigned, the option I am adding inside `save()` can not be seen after the product saves; however, if I add a custom option from the admin form and then save, my option added in `save()` does get added. It seems the option will only get saved if the product already has a custom option assigned through the admin

I am guessing I am missing something basic, but can't seem to find what it is.

---

EDIT

I took a look at the `catalog_product_option` table, and the option I add in `save()` is listed here, but it doesn't appear on the product's custom options tab unless I add an additional option manually from admin.

---

EDIT 2

It seems that `$product->setHasOptions()` isn't working. When I look at `catalog_product_entity`, that value is 0. Manually changing it to 1 resolves the issue.

**How am I supposed to save custom product type data while in the `save()` method?**

Comment: This is a common problem. A way around is to wrap your rourine in a registry flag. So action if flag is not set. Set flag when actioned. This will block the recursion.

Answer (score 0):

I was working on something similar today - I would try to get all current options, push your new option(s) onto that array and do this:

```
Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product_option')->unsetOptions();
$product->setProductOptions($options);
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true)
    ->setHasOptions(true);
$product->save();
```

The first line is explained here (not sure if you'd need it actually): https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4006260/magento-accumulating-custom-options-in-script

Edit: By the way, this code is working perfectly for me, however I'm using it in a script in development

Comment: `$product->save()` calls itself as I am currently working inside `save()`. This would just cause recursion.